# How to organise columnar data into a network table

Tags: python, unix

I have a tab delimited file text file with two columns. I need to find a way that prints all values that “hit” each other to one line.

For example, my input looks like this:

```
A   B
A   C
A   D
B   C
B   D
C   D
B   E
D   E
B   F
C   F
F   G
F   H
H   I
K   L
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
A   B   C   D
B   D   E
B   C   F
F   G   H
H   I
K   L
```

My actual data file is much larger than this if that makes any difference. I would prefer to do this in Unix or Python where possible.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't the second be `B C D`?

Comment: awk '{ list[$1] = list[$1] "\t" $2 } END { for (i in list) printf "%s%s\n", i, list[i] }' foo.txt

Comment: I may have made an error Padraic, but it looks to be right to me. Why do you think its     B C D     instead of    B D E?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to put input file as `.csv`? It would be easier to parse delimiters.

If it wouldn't be posible, try next example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
with open('example.txt','rb') as txtfile:
    cleaned = []
    #store file information in a list of lists
    for line in txtfile.readlines():
        cleaned.append(line.split())
    #group py first element of nested list
    for elt, items in groupby(cleaned, itemgetter(0)):
        row = [elt]
        for item in items:
            row.append(item[1])
        print row
```

Hope it helps you.

Solution using a `.csv` file:

```
from itertools import groupby 
from operator import itemgetter 
import csv 
with open('example.csv','rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t') 
    for row in reader: 
         cleaned.append(row) #group py first element of nested list 
    for elt, items in groupby(cleaned, itemgetter(0)): 
        row = [elt] 
        for item in items: 
            row.append(item[1]) 
        print row
```

Comment: Thanks, Pasqual, it would be possible to convert to a .csv file first. What would you recommend?

Comment: Hi, Lacura.  Its almost the same but, instead of using readlines() and line.split() would be much pretty and confortable to use `csv` python library.

There I give you an example:
`from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
with open('example.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        cleaned.append(row)
    #group py first element of nested list
    for elt, items in groupby(cleaned, itemgetter(0)):
        row = [elt]
        for item in items:
            row.append(item[1])
        print row`

Comment: @Lacura if this answer solved your problem you should accept it.  You and Pasqual will both gain reputation and it will mark the question as having an accepted answer

Comment: @PasqualGuerrero With all that extra code in a comment it would probably be better to edit your answer to include it--the formatting is much better if nothing else

Comment: @EricRenouf Yes, i forgot to update it :)  Thank you.